# Defaulting a ComboBox value to any of its childs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have an Array bound to a ComboBox.

My issue is that **I can't find a way to default ComboBox element** to any of the ones in the Array, i.e. it's empty when loading the User Control.

Would this be due to the way I load the array (from a dictionnary)?

**XAML binding:**

```
<WrapPanel>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ExclusionDescriptions}" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Description, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectedIndex="0"/>
</WrapPanel>
```

**Code:**

```
public string[] ExclusionDescriptions 
{
    get
    {
        return GetDescriptionsAndEntityScope().Keys.ToArray(); 
    }
}
```

With:

```
    private Dictionary<string, bool> GetDescriptionsAndEntityScope()
    {
        return GetDescriptionsAndEntityScope();
    }
```

Comment: How are you setting the `Description` property? Does it have a value?

Comment: Yes, there is some values. The dropdown is populated, just that the selection when loaded is on nothing (empty selection). Would like to default it to the first element for example

Comment: How about this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910896/display-a-default-value-for-a-databound-wpf-combobox)

Comment: when your viewmodel or control starts up, set the Description property to ExclusionDescriptions[0], and ensure that NotifyPropertyChanged is raised

Comment: Can we see your code for `Description`?

Comment: Try binding SelectedItem or SelectedIndex. It may work..

Comment: Thank you all. Set this in the code as I couldn't make this working with triggers in the XAML. Not big fan though of doing so, and not sure why this doesn't work by default.
SelectedExclusionDescription = CouterpartyLevelExclusionDescriptions[0];)

Comment: set SelectedIndex="0" in XAML.  It may work for your case